# PendingIntent on Notification foreground service android

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an activity in my app. When i click one option, start running my service foreground with a notification like this:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Radio.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification  notification = new Notification();
    notification.tickerText = "Connecting RadiO!.. Wait..";
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "radiO!",
            "Playing: " + songName, pi);
    startForeground(1, notification);
```

Then, still running my activity, I click on my notification and I opened it without closing the previous activity. I must not have the same activity twice.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a new instance of the activity you are trying to execute each time you click on the notification, in order to avoid it and reuse an already existing activity(if any), just set the activity as singleTask in the AndroidManifest.xml as shown below:

```
    <activity
       android:name=".YourActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: When i click the notification, start the new activity and close the notification

Comment: Work it!! thank you, and need for my app too this:

android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"